# :: moment() :: jQuery Convert and Compare entered value with the given date

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I want to check the date (already printed) with User entered value is Future date or Past date.

I am showing default date as after 2 days and If User enters 1 in the given text field it should say as "**Past**" Date or If the user enters 3 or more in the text filed, it should say as "**Future**"

**********  [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/52u70jmp/15/)  ***********

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var inputDate = jQuery(this).val();
  var myDateNew = moment().add(2, 'days').format('MMM DD, YYYY');  
  jQuery('#myDate').text(myDateNew);

  jQuery(document).on('keyup', '#inputDate', function () {

    if ($('#inputDate').val() > myDateNew) {
      jQuery('#dateCheck').text('Future');
    }

    else if ($('#inputDate').val() < myDateNew) {
      jQuery('#dateCheck').text('Past');
    }


  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Date: <span id="myDate"></span>

<br>
<input type="text" name="inputDate" id="inputDate" value="" placeholder="Enter number">

<div id="compare">
Entered date is : <span id="dateCheck"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a moment object with your date before compare it

```
moment().add($('#inputDate').val(), 'days') > moment(myDateNew)
```

e.g.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var inputDate = jQuery(this).val();
  var myDateNew = moment().add(2, 'days').format('MMM DD, YYYY');  
  jQuery('#myDate').text(myDateNew);

  jQuery(document).on('keyup', '#inputDate', function () {

    var diff = moment().add($('#inputDate').val(), 'days');
    if (diff > moment(myDateNew)) {
      jQuery('#dateCheck').text('Future');
    }

    else if (diff < moment(myDateNew)) {
      jQuery('#dateCheck').text('Past');
    }


  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Date: <span id="myDate"></span>

<br>
<input type="text" name="inputDate" id="inputDate" value="" placeholder="Enter number">

<div id="compare">
Entered date is : <span id="dateCheck"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this? Input a number (e.g: 1, 2, 3 ....)? 
If so you just need add your inputted number to current date then compare it to your showed date.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var inputDate = jQuery(this).val();
  var myDateNew = moment().add(2, 'days').format('MMM DD, YYYY');  
  jQuery('#myDate').text(myDateNew);

  jQuery(document).on('keyup', '#inputDate', function () {
    var inputDate = moment().add($('#inputDate').val(), 'days').format('MMM DD, YYYY');
    if (inputDate > myDateNew) {
      jQuery('#dateCheck').text('Future');
    }

    else if (inputDate < myDateNew) {
      jQuery('#dateCheck').text('Past');
    } else {
     jQuery('#dateCheck').text('Present');
    }


  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Date: <span id="myDate"></span>

<br>
<input type="text" name="inputDate" id="inputDate" value="" placeholder="Enter number">

<div id="compare">
Entered date is : <span id="dateCheck"></span>
</div>
```

---

Otherwise, check other people's answer because they focus on date input.

---

**Disclaimer: I am slightly confused with your question. Idk if the input should be a number or a date.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `myDateNew` variable returns a `Date` Object. The `$('#inputDate').val()` returns a `number`. But following your question you want only to check the values entered in the input field. I think you want to check if the entered value is greater or less then day of the `myDateNew` Object. You have to call the  `myDateNew.getDate()` which will returns the day.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      var inputDate = jQuery(this).val();
      var myDateNew = moment().add(2, 'days').format('MMM DD, YYYY');  
      jQuery('#myDate').text(myDateNew);

      jQuery(document).on('keyup', '#inputDate', function () {
        if ($('#inputDate').val() > myDateNew.getDate()) {
          jQuery('#dateCheck').text('Future');
        }
        else if ($('#inputDate').val() < myDateNew.getDate()) {
          jQuery('#dateCheck').text('Past');
        }
      });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myDateNew = moment().add(2, 'days');
  $('#myDate').text(myDateNew.format('MMM DD, YYYY'));
  $('#inputDate').val(myDateNew.format('L'));
  var myDateNew = myDateNew.toDate();

  $(document).on('keyup', '#inputDate', function () {
    var inputDate = new Date($(this).val());
    var text = "";
    if (!inputDate || inputDate.toString() === "Invalid Date") {
      text = "Enter valid date";
    } else if (inputDate > myDateNew) {      
      text = 'Future';
    } else if (inputDate < myDateNew) {
      text = 'Past';
    } else {
      text = 'Now';
    }
    $('#dateCheck').text(text);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
Date: <span id="myDate"></span>
<br/>   
<input type="text" name="inputDate" id="inputDate" value="" placeholder="Enter number" />
<div id="compare">
  Entered date is : <span id="dateCheck"></span>
</div>
</div>
```